# Как сделать кастомные исключения в laravel

Tags: php, laravel, исключения

До сих пор полностью не понял, для чего нужны исключения и конструкции try-catch, если есть if-else? Ведь с помощью if else также можно остановить выполнение программы в нужном месте и выдать ошибку. Объясните необходимость исключений на примере laravel

Comment: [Цитата из оф.документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.exceptions.php): `Замечание:

Внутренние функции PHP в основном используют сообщения об ошибках, и только новые объектно-ориентированные расширения используют исключения. Однако, ошибки можно легко преобразовать в исключения с помощью класса ErrorException.` __try-catch__ работают с исключениями, в то время как __if-else__ это операторы для ветвления кода программы.

Comment: не заморачивайтесь на пхп в целом и тем более на ларавел. Принцип работы исключений и предназначение этого механизма общий для большинства языков программирования. Почитайте про исключения в целом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну тут все просто пример с if и else

Допустим есть одна точка обработки запросов в index.php

```
$body = runApplication();
if($body['status'] == false ) {
   echo 'Error: ' . $body['message'];
} else {
   echo $body['body'];
}

// далее где то в runApplication есть автолод классов к примеру
// расмотрим функцию рендера главной страницы

function render() {
   if(renderBlock1) {
     return ['status' => false, 'msg' => 'error'];
   }

   if(renderBlock2) {
     return ['status' => false, 'msg' => 'error 2'];
   }
   // и т.д.
}

function renderBlock()
{
 /// какая то логика с ошибкой 
 return []; // снова обработка и ошибки и т.д.
}
```

А еще надо описать логику остановки приложения, и т.д. и т.п. вот именно такую логику и делают exception это некая ошибка по причине которой программа не может дальше работать. От слова 'неожиданость';

Теперь к рассмотрим пример с Exception

```
try {
   appRun();
} catch (Exception $error) {
   echo 'Error: ' . $error->getMessage();
}

// и теперь все что надо сделать это просто выкинуть exception
function rederBlock1 {
  // какая то логика с ошибкой
  throw new Exception('Error');
}
```

Comment: Дело в том, что laravel игнорирует блоки try  в контроллере и в случае ошибки сразу возвращает свою страницу ошибки Whoops!

Comment: Не может игнорировать, код добавьте с блоком вашего try cath